# issues using Google Cloud Vision API in a shared github repo

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-repository

I was running my code locally with the google cloud vision CLI SDK package installed, but wanted to add it to a shared github repo for a project and the SDK is too large to do so. I am confused by the steps on the google cloud website and was hoping someone who has done it could give me a step by step of how to use the API with code on a shared repo